# The end of an audio file that's looping?

Tags: c#, loops, naudio, soundplayer

I'm trying to create a simple audio Looper to record my own songs. For those of you who don't know what an audio Looper is, you first record a layer of a song(let's say a piece of piano) then you start Looping that piece to add a piece of guitar on top of that layered. Since I already know how to add both together that's not the issue. But I would like to safe my layer which I add every time on top of that layer, so I would have to check if the audio file I loop is restarting or not. To safe a 2nd file with the layer to add. Mix it together afterwards(since you can't write 2 different streams in 1 file) and loop that.

For the Looping I am using the SoudPlayer Class using System.Media.

```
Player = new SoundPlayer(path);
Player.PlayLooping();

int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);

sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(open.FileName, sourceStream.WaveFormat);

sourceStream.StartRecording();
```

The recording should stop everytime the audio file is at the end.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need take a look on the NAudio [documentation](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RecordWavFileWinFormsWaveIn.md).

> One safety feature I often add when recording WAV is to limit the size of a WAV file. They grow quickly and can't be over 4GB in any case. Here I'll request that recording stops after 30 seconds:

```
waveIn.DataAvailable += (s, a) =>
{
    writer.Write(a.Buffer, 0, a.BytesRecorded);
    if (writer.Position > waveIn.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 30)
    {
        waveIn.StopRecording();
    }
};
```